# How to setup GIMP add-ons

Tags: macos, gimp

I'm trying to setup androidicon.py file after I downloaded it from internet, but I can not find the menu item *Android Icon batch mode* and *Android Icon* even though I reboot it.
What I did as follows:

1. Download it from http://registry.gimp.org/node/25274
2. Control+click on androidicon.py.txt link and save it as file "androidicon.py".
3. Copy it to plug-in folder
4. Reboot GIMP
5. Confirm the menu "Android Icon batch mode" and "Android Icon" wasn't shown.

Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I fixed this by myself by giving execution rights to .py file like below. sudo chmod +x ~/Library/Application\ Support/GIMP/2.8/plug-ins/androidicon.py

Comment: You'll be able to post your solution as an answer and accept it. It will be helpful for other users facing the same problem.